# On convergence and Lebesgue Integration

Tags: lebesgue-integral, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

Good evening,

I have some problems with following task because I don't understand the context between the forms of convergence and $L$-integrability :

Let $f_n$ be an $L$-integrable sequence on $[1,\infty)$. Prove or disprove thefollowing statements:

a) If $f(_n)$ converges pointwise to $f$ on $[1,\infty)$, then f is $L$-integrable on $[1,\infty)$

b) If $f(_n)$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $[1,\infty)$, then $f$ is $L$-integrable on $[1,\infty)$

c) If $f(_n)$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $[1,\infty$) and $f$ is $L$-integrable on $[1,\infty)$, then: $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}{} \int_{1}^{\infty} f_n(x)  = \int_{1}^{\infty} f(x)\,dx$.

I guess a) and b) are not true but c) is true, but it not sure why
I can't give a counterexample, but i guess if I take unbounded $f_n$?

Maybe you can help me
(Sorry for the language I translated this exercise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that $a)$ and $b)$ are false. For $a),$ simply check $f_n=1_{[1,n]}$ with limit $f=1$. For $b)$, check $f_n(x)=1_{[1,n]}(x) \frac{1}{x}$. Of course, that's *also* a counter example for $a)$.

As a matter of fact, $c)$ is *also* wrong. See $f(x)=0$ and $f_n=\frac{1}{n} 1_{[1,n+1]}$.

Note that none of these counter-examples involve any unbounded functions.

Comment: thanks! One more Question for c) i thought if $f_n$ converts univformly i can change lim and integral but why I can't do it here?

Comment: Because that only holds for finite measures. Check the proof that uniform convergence implies convergence of integrals on $[a,b]$ and see that it plays a vital role that the measure is finite.

Comment: Oh,okay! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: It looks to me like the point of the exercise is to highlight the importance of the dominated convergence theorem as more or less the only general theorem to guarantee $L^1$-convergence. As you get deeper into the theory of $L^p$-spaces, your question is very closely related to the question: When is $L^p\subseteq L^{p'}$? The answer here depends heavily on the measure.

Comment: Sorry, relooked this exercise i have problems with the notation u gave in c) 
what means $1_{[1,n+1}$

Comment: The indicator function on $[1,n+1]$? It's not that different from the other examples.